Plotly Figures not displaying in Quarto
I have an IPYNB file (notebook downloaded from Google Colab). It has a cell in it that makes a chart in plotly:
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3])
fig.show()

I see the chart in the notebook, but not when I render that notebook as a source file for a Quarto project.
Plotly figures do get displayed when rendered from a .QMD file, but I want to use .IPYNB because my notebook has taken advantage of Colab-specific functionality, like forms, notebook secrets, etc.
My question is: how can I get plotly figures to be properly displayed in Quarto, using a .IPYNB file source, in such a way that will work BOTH in colab and in Quarto?
UPDATE: here is some investigation code. It appears different renderers work on colab vs quarto, but there is no overlap?

Could you please share your yaml in your .ipynb file?

There's no yml front matter in the ipynb file

Since there is no overlapping between the two environments, however there are some modes work in each environment I suggest using the snippet code below to detect the current environment and then set the renderer accordingly as follows:
import plotly.io as pio
import IPython


def get_environment():
    try:
        # Check if running in Google Colab
        if 'google.colab' in str(IPython.get_ipython()):
            return 'colab'
    except NameError:
        pass
    
    try:
        # Check if running in Quarto
        if 'quarto' in IPython.get_ipython().config:
            return 'quarto'
    except:
        pass
    
    # Default to Jupyter Notebook 
    return 'notebook'

env = get_environment()

if env == 'colab':
    pio.renderers.default = 'colab'
elif env == 'quarto':
    pio.renderers.default = 'notebook'
else:
    pio.renderers.default = 'notebook'

Update:
Since you should only run the notebook on the Colab and then import the notebook to Quarto without running the cells. Thus, you need to download the notebook below as .ipynb. But ensure that the figures are included in the downloaded notebook. Please, do not forget to use pio.renderers.default = 'png' since it ensures that if Quarto renders the notebook without execution, it will display the pre-rendered PNG images from the Colab run.
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import IPython

def is_colab():
    try:
        if 'google.colab' in str(IPython.get_ipython()):
            return True
    except NameError:
        return False

if is_colab():
    pio.renderers.default = 'colab'
else:
    pio.renderers.default = 'png'  # Use static PNG for Quarto

# Create the plot
fig = px.line(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3])
fig.show()

Another important step is to add quarto.yml beside the downloaded notebook. Add the following configuration to quarto.yml to ensure that Quarto does not re-execute the notebook and uses the pre-rendered output from Colab:
project:
  type: website

jupyter:
  execute:
    execute_notebooks: false

I think that this approach will help you see the Plotly figures in Quarto as they were rendered in Colab without requiring Quarto to re-execute the notebook.

I believe the notebook is only run once, in Colab. It is desired to not run it again locally, due to Colab specific functionality

I used this to be able to preview plotly graphs in quarto in Windows. I used only the pio.renderers.default = 'notebook' and it worked.
